# Java Graphics object out of Bounds

Tags: java, graphics

Is there a pre-defined function in java that prevents a `Graphics` object from moving out of the frame?

I am using `KeyListener` and `ActionListener` classes to move the object.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not, you need to manually set up collision boundaries.